# Pass Birt report radio button value and column value to bean class

Tags: jquery, jsf, xhtml, birt

I have created a Birt report which have some columns like storeId, storeName and also I have written HTML code for radio button. Now I am displaying this BIRT report on XHTML page. I want some help like, I want to pass the selected radio button value and storeId, which is just an column value to my JSF bean class.

Can any one help with this. Is somwthing I can do with jquery then please let me know.

Comment: This question does not show an attempt to solve the problem before asking for help.

Comment: does not an attempt means ?? What you want from my side ?

Comment: Show that you are trying to solve the problem, not just have someone solve it for you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its nothing such that I haven't tried anything and waiting for someone here who will solve it for me. I have tried it by writing JavaScript but its not working out so asked here Sir.